# Angular js use of controller in this example

Tags: angularjs

I am reading the Angular JS [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/%24httpBackend) I am looking at this example:

```
// testing controller
    describe('MyController', function() {
       var $httpBackend, $rootScope, createController;

       beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
         // Set up the mock http service responses
         $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
         // backend definition common for all tests
         $httpBackend.when('GET', '/auth.py').respond({userId: 'userX'}, {'A-Token': 'xxx'});

         // Get hold of a scope (i.e. the root scope)
         $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
         // The $controller service is used to create instances of controllers
         var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');

         createController = function() {
           return $controller('MyController', {'$scope' : $rootScope });
         };
       }));
```

My question is what purpose the `createController` serves, I don't really understand why it is there or what the last line does where `$controller` is returned or what it has to do with the `$scope`.

It is the second grey section that contains code underneath the header: **Unit testing with mock $httpBackend**.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$controller` returns an instance of `MyController` from the first grey section.  To give the controller some context, it passes the `$rootScope` into the instantiation of the controller.  Hence when you *execute* the controller (as shown in subsequent it() blocks) the controller runs and kicks off the `$http.get('/auth.py')` request.